# Contract "Evolution" should be marked as abstract

Tags: ethereum, solidity

```
  //SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0-or-later
  pragma solidity 0.8.13;

  import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
  import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/IERC721Enumerable.sol";
  import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
  import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol";
  import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";
  import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";
  import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
  import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Royalty.sol";
  import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721Receiver.sol";


  ERC721 constant EXAMPLE_CONTRACT = ERC721(0x45cA56EE242F14419499D60cd5876E07d54394cE);
  IERC721 constant EXAMPLE_CONTRACTIERC721 = IERC721(0x45cA56EE242F14419499D60cd5876E07d54394cE);
  IERC721Enumerable constant EXAMPLE_CONTRACTENUMARABLE = IERC721Enumerable(0x45cA56EE242F14419499D60cd5876E07d54394cE);



  contract Evolution is IERC721Receiver{

        function change(uint256 gen1tokenId) external {

           EXAMPLE_CONTRACT.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), gen1tokenId);
           
        }

     
  }
```

For example, when I add anything to the contract;
contract Evolutin is ERC721, ERC721Enumarable ....
it always gives me this error. It wants abstract contract Evolution as a solution, but I don't want it that way. Because then it doesn't work while deploying.

**Contract "Evolution" should be marked as abstract.
--> contracts/new_contract.sol:21:7:
|**

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Evolution` contract implements the [IERC721Receiver](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.6.0/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721Receiver.sol) interface that defines the `onERC721Received()` function, so you need to implement the function.

```
contract Evolution is IERC721Receiver {
    function change(uint256 gen1tokenId) external {
        EXAMPLE_CONTRACT.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), gen1tokenId);
    }

    function onERC721Received(
        address operator,
        address from,
        uint256 tokenId,
        bytes calldata data
    ) override external returns (bytes4) {
        // TODO your implementation; or leave it empty
        return this.onERC721Received.selector;
    }
}
```

Comment: lol i tried the same but it didn't work, thank you mate <3